# flutter MultiProvider Consumer

Tags: flutter, dart

I use providers in my app, below code is working but doesnt look right :)
Looking for some help how reformat the code to only use child once..

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AppProvider(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(true),
        ),
      ],
      child: Consumer<AppProvider>(
        builder: (ctx, providerApp, _) => Container(
          child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(
            builder: (ctx, providerTheme, _) => MaterialApp(
              debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
              theme: providerTheme.getTheme(),
              home: Splash(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You're not even using providerApp so just remove the outer Consumer.

Comment: Thank you i!!   AppProvider was always there I was thinking its always needed..